# Issues in using Office UI Fabric datepicker with Aurelia

Tags: jquery-plugins, requirejs, aurelia, pickadate, office-ui-fabric

I am trying to use [Office UI Fabric datepicker](http://officeuifabric.com/components/date-picker/) with my Aurelia app. Based on the example provided this what I have done so far:

1. Created a custom element around datepicker:

   - `msfabric-date-picker.html`:

     ```
     <template>
       <div class="ms-DatePicker">
       ...
       </div>
     </template>
     ```
   - `msfabric-date-picker.ts`:

     ```
     export class MsfabricDatePickerCustomElement {
         static inject = [Element];

         constructor(public element: Element) {
         }

         attached() {
             var self = this;
             if ($.fn.DatePicker) {
                 $(self.element).DatePicker();
             }
         }
     }
     ```
2. Usage of datepicker custom element:

   ```
   <require from="./msfabric-date-picker"></require>
   ....
   <msfabric-date-picker if.bind="isDate"></msfabric-date-picker>
   ```
3. Added the Office-Fabric date-picker library in the layout html page:

   ```
   <script src="~/Scripts/office-ui-fabric/Jquery.DatePicker.js"></script>
   ```

   And here lies the problem. As far as I have understood, this fabric component depends on [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/), and there is `require.js` error of `Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module` while loading the `pickadate.js` jquery plugin. I have tried replacing the code in `Jquery.DatePicker.js` with the one in the codepen as provided [here](http://officeuifabric.com/components/date-picker/), but without success. I even tried directly adding the `pickadate.js` scripts `picker.js`, and `picker.date.js`, before adding the fabric script, but again without success. In all the cases, I am getting the same error.

I think the [problem](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch) is how the `pickadate.js` module is being loaded. Need your help to resolve this.

Comment: try using the whole library jquery.fabric.min.js,that should make some difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used requireJs to load the libraries instead of adding `<script src="~/Scripts/office-ui-fabric/Jquery.DatePicker.js"></script>` in my HTML, as follows:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: baseUrl + "/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min",
        "pickadate-legacy": baseUrl + "/Scripts/pickadate/legacy",
        picker: baseUrl + "/Scripts/pickadate/picker",
        pickadate: baseUrl + "/Scripts/pickadate/picker.date",
        officeUiFabric: baseUrl + "/Scripts/office-ui-fabric/jquery.fabric.min"
    },
    shim: {
        picker: ['jquery', 'pickadate-legacy'],
        pickadate: {
                deps: ['jquery', 'picker'],
                exports: 'DatePicker'
            },
        officeUiFabric: ['jquery', 'pickadate']
    }
});

require(["aurelia dependencies"], function (au) {
    require(['jquery', 'picker', 'pickadate', 'officeUiFabric'], function () {});
});
```

It seems to be working as of now :)

Comment: One question not related, when running sample "Form.html", does the date picker double up month section to you?

Comment: Actually there are still some unexpected behavior from the Datepicker Component. I was initially referring to [this](http://officeuifabric.com/components/date-picker/), and I got 2 Datepicker components in my page. I later used only `<div class="ms-DatePicker"></div>` as [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-UI-Fabric/blob/release/1.1.3/dist/components/DatePicker/DatePicker.html) instead of the full markup. I took a brief look at the JavaScript part of the same and it seems that the markup generation is done by JavaScript anyway. Hope this helps.

Comment: However, it seems that I might need to revert to full markup as can be seen [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-UI-Fabric/pull/179).

Comment: I will probably wait "component" to be more mature, but css frame work is looking really good.